# Changing the displayed direction of an image while it's moving in OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl

I'm doing a little something in openGL now and I'm trying to make it so that whichever direction an object is heading, that object displays that direction clearly.

e.g.
If an object that is a dog is heading SW, it should be pointing southwest.

Is there any simple way to do this? glRotatef seems like it would be a valid option at first but I feel like it would get sticky when trying to calculate the angle and all.  Especially since this would need to be updated constantly.

Comment: glRotatef sounds indeed like the simplest way to achieve your goal. Calculating an angle isn't that sticky.
You could also rotate the texture coordinates of your mesh, but THAT would be sticky ;)

Comment: Well, I'm not really sure how to go about then I guess.  Could you help at all?

Comment: Rotate _then_ translate.

Comment: Sure! What is your current orientation data (how is represented the southwest in your code) ?

Comment: Well, I have a position vector of my object and a velocity vector of my object if that helps.  I was just using SW as an example.  The movement is all done randomly.

Comment: If you are in 2D (it seems so), atan2(speed.y, speed.x) should give you the appropriate angle.

Comment: I'm actually in 3d.  I'm using x,y,z coordinates.

Comment: Oooookay then you could directly compute the model's rotation matrix and feed OpenGL with it.
If V is your velocity vector, then the 'side' vector S is cross(V, (0,1,0)) and the 'up' vector U is cross(S, V).
This actually what the method gluLookAt does if you're familiar with it.

The final rotation matrix should look like [S, U, V]

Comment: Do you mean side or do you mean center?  Because I'm used to eye, center, up.

Comment: Your speed vector is equivalent to (eye-center): it merely represents a direction. As for me it's the more reliable way to create a rotation matrix, I had too many bad suprises when I tried to extract Euler angles.
But you should try it out, that's the best way to learn :)

Comment: You don't use gluLookAt! I meant its internal working is the same as the algorithm I described. Sorry but you'll have to do it by hand.